# ¿Cómo eliminar splash screen en ionic usando capacitor?

Tags: ionic, screen, capacitor, splash

Estoy realizando una app, de la cual necesito que no se ejecute el splash screen, he visto respuestas basadas en cordoba, yo estoy usando capacitor. He intentado varias formas pero no obtengo resultados favorables.

```
"SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0,
      "launchAutoHide": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffffff"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si `launchShowDuration` es 0 entonces lo que se muestra no es el SplashScreen, solo es el background que ha sido modificado parar mostrar el icono de capacitor.

Para quitarlo en Android hay que abrir el proyecto Android y en el AndroidManifest
remover el tema de la Activity.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" --> remover esta línea
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Comment: Lo voy a intentar, pero hablando genéricamente solo funcionaría en android? en ios supongo que se seguiría viendo, no? Aún no lo he emulado ahí, por eso tengo mis dudas.

Comment: Sí, solo funciona en Android. IOS debe tener un equivalente a eso.